# Resize iCheck JQuery Radion Button

Tags: css, angularjs, icheck

I am using [iCheck Plugin](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck) for radio buttons using Angular Directive but i am not able to resize the radio button size as i need small size radio button.

Can Anyone help for same ?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805394/how-to-change-size-of-icheck-checkbox-and-add-border-radius

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like iCheck is built to allow for size changes.  The classes reference png sprites for the button style overlays.  There are 2x png image sprites in the icheck folders, but it looks like those are used to handle High-DPI displays.

Your best bet is to create additional png sprites using photoshop.  Then add a new style definition to the existing or new css files.  The new style would reference your larger png file.  You would have to adjust the height, width, and positioning to accommodate your new size.

I have not tried this yet, but I will probably be doing something similar soon so I can have a larger iCheck radio button for mobile devices.  In my case I might use a media query so it sizes iCheck accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied and rewrited green.css to **green-2x.css** and it works fine. You have to just change CSS **background** to **green@2x.png**.

```js
$('input.flat-2x').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green-2x',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green-2x'
});
```

```css
/* iCheck plugin Flat skin, green 2x
----------------------------------- */
.icheckbox_flat-green-2x,
.iradio_flat-green-2x {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/flat/green@2x.png) no-repeat !important;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icheckbox_flat-green-2x {
    background-position: 0 0 !important;
}
.icheckbox_flat-green-2x.checked {
    background-position: -44px 0 !important;
}
.icheckbox_flat-green-2x.disabled {
    background-position: -88px 0 !important;
    cursor: default;
}
.icheckbox_flat-green-2x.checked.disabled {
    background-position: -132px 0 !important;
}

.iradio_flat-green-2x {
    background-position: -176px 0 !important;
}
.iradio_flat-green-2x.checked {
    background-position: -220px 0 !important;
}
.iradio_flat-green-2x.disabled {
    background-position: -264px 0 !important;
    cursor: default;
}
.iradio_flat-green-2x.checked.disabled {
    background-position: -308px 0 !important;
}

/* HiDPI support */
@media (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    .icheckbox_flat-green-2x,
    .iradio_flat-green-2x {
        background-image: url(green@2x.png);
        -webkit-background-size: 352px 44px;
        background-size: 352px 44px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="flat-2x">

<input type="radio" name="name" class="flat-2x">
<input type="radio" name="name" class="flat-2x">
```

Answer (score 0):

I resized the image sizes in sprite (skins/minimal/blue.png) like this : [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvA0i.png)

I hope this helps you! :)