# How to change size of checkbox and add border radius of icheck plugin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, icheck

I am using `icheck` in my project. I want to change the `size` of the checkbox and add `border-radius` to checkbox.

I tried many examples.

**My code is:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap/master/icheck-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    .c-radius{
    border-radius:5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="checkbox icheck-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="primary" class="c-radius"/>
        <label for="primary">Keep username same as email id</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > label {
    padding-left: 22px !important;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child + input[type="hidden"] + label::before, .icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child + label::before {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: -22px;
}

.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label::after,
.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child:checked + label::after {
    top: 0px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 8px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```css
.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > label{
  padding-left:22px !important;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child + input[type="hidden"] + label::before, .icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child + label::before{
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-left:-22px;
}

.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label::after, 
.icheck-primary[class*="icheck-"] > input:first-child:checked + label::after{
  top:0px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap/master/icheck-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    .c-radius{
    border-radius:5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="checkbox icheck-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="primary" class="c-radius"/>
        <label for="primary">Keep username same as email id</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if there possible to change the size and make a smaller checkbox

Comment: Should we change color without using predefined class

Comment: why to use library?,  used to custom css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199009/discussion-between-pritesh-and-lalji-tadhani).